# What voltage to expect on the resistor in RC circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis

Please help me understand how the voltage signal changes on the resistor in the attached RC circuit.

My expectation would be that when the source of the AC voltage signal (PR2) is in the positive part of its sinus signal, the voltage measured on resistor (PR4) will be actually negative.

I assume this because to my understanding, at this particular moment the side of capacitor connected to the resistor should contain negative charge.

But as you'll see in the attached picture the simulation of such circuit (designed in multisim.com) shows that the voltage measured on the resistor has the same polarity as the voltage measured on the capacitor. How is that possible? Isn't it violating the physics of allocation of charge on the capacitor?

[image]

**Added** (29th July 2022) circuit simulation for series of capacitors
[image]

Comment: Wouldn't it be fantastic if we put +5 volt on one side of a capacitor and there appeared minus 5 volts on the other side. Just saying. But, on the other hand, if we grounded one terminal of a capacitor then we could not possibly force the ungrounded end to be anything other than 0 volts. I prefer it, on balance, that capacitors work as they are expected to work.

Comment: It would help to understand **why** you think it would be negative, and why do you think the simulation breaks laws of physics, while your expectations would break laws of physics. The simulation looks perfectly normal as would be expected.

Comment: @Justme the left plate has +1V on it, and has a bunch of missing electrons, so it would make sense that the right plate, having the same number of electrons *extra*, would be at -1V, wouldn't you think?

Comment: Basically I’m just trying to get my head around the fact that in the simulation that I attached there is the same voltage behind the capacitor as before the capacitor. How that happens? On what principle it does work?

Comment: @Gladik do you just care about what the capacitor does, or do you also care how the electrons move to make it work that way?

Comment: @user253751 Actually yes, I'd like to understand fundamentals (e.g. electron movement) that are behind this behavior.

Comment: @user253751 This is all very helpful, many thanks for that. I was wondering about it a long time as I came across it in amplifiers where capacitor (C) is used to separate DC from AC and now it makes more sense. As it was several times mentioned here, important is that C is connected inside the closed circle loop (can feel el. field from both sides). However, I'm still wondering how C works when it's used to connect antenna to the circuit because in that case other end of the antenna is not connected to the earth and despite that it still somehow works. Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

> I assume this because to my understanding, at this particular moment the side of capacitor connected to the resistor should contain negative charge.

The externally observable behavior of the capacitor depends on the *net charge* stored in it. The internal distribution of charge between the plates is an “implementation detail”. To a first approximation, it has no effect on how the capacitor behaves.

The voltage on the capacitor is proportional to the net charge stored, and the proportionality factor is the reciprocal of the capacitance. 1F = 1C/1V, by definition.

As the capacitor is initially discharged, the voltage across it must be zero since the net charge is zero. This doesn’t of course mean that there are no charge carriers inside the capacitor: there are, but their influence on the electric field potential (voltage!) between the plates sums up to zero.

Equivalently, a discharged capacitor acts instantaneously as a short circuit: a voltage source set to 0V, by definition. That answers your question as to why the voltage “passes through” the capacitor. When discharged, the voltage across the cap is zero, so the potential on both sides of the capacitor must be **equal**: that’s what zero voltage *means*! Voltage is electric field potential difference between two points. A discharged capacitor maintains the same potential on both sides of it. Thus, the voltage “passes through”. Or, more clearly, the electric field passes through without a change in potential. Once the net charge on the capacitor is nonzero, there is a “step” change in electric field potential as seen from outside the plates. Internally, the field potential of course changes in a continuous fashion.

The only way to change to voltage on the capacitor is by changing its net charge, and for this a current must flow. So, at any chosen point in time, a capacitor is just a voltage source, with the *rate* of voltage change proportional to the instantaneous current and inversely proportional to the capacitance. But, since we’re looking at a point in time, there’s a definite instantaneous voltage across the capacitor, and at that moment it acts as-if it was a voltage source.

For DC static analysis, as done in SPICE for example, the default source voltage on capacitors is set to zero, but it doesn’t have to be that way - you can set it to whatever you think will match the operating point of the circuit best, to speed up the convergence of the solution.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications. You mentioned that capacitor maintains its potential on both sides. In a circuit with the voltage source it continues doing the same. But my question would be how is that maintenance of potential achieved? Could we say that if first capacitor plate is connected to positive potential, electric field locks/attracts electrons on the second plate and this lack of locked electrons actually results into positive charge also on the second plate?

Comment: And in addition, if we add another capacitor in a series with the first one, the "generated" positive potential on the second plate of the first capacitor will cause the same effect on the second capacitor?

Comment: This is all very helpful, many thanks for that. I was wondering about it a long time as I came across it in amplifiers where capacitor (C) is used to separate DC from AC and now it makes more sense. As it was several times mentioned here, important is that C is connected inside the closed circle loop (can feel el. field from both sides). However, I'm still wondering how C works when it's used to connect antenna to the circuit because in that case other end of the antenna is not connected to the earth and despite that it still somehow works. Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Approaching the circuit from many different aspects, it does not have much effect.

So the answer to your question is, the expected output voltage at the resistor is approximately same as the input voltage, as the capacitor does not have time to accumulate enough charge to have any significant voltage over it, so if the capacitor voltage is approximated to be always zero, then Vout = Vin.

1. It's a 1st order high pass filter with 1.6 Hz cutoff frequency. If you draw a Bode plot with that approximation, it has no effect to a 10 Hz signal.
2. It's a voltage divider, with 1k at bottom, and at 10 Hz, the 100 uF capacitor has an impedance of 159 ohms, which is much less than 1k. Again the approximation should be based on the impedances being about a decade apart, that it does not do much. Therefore the output is much closer to input signal than 0V. Output is approximately 86% of input.
3. The RC network has a time constant (Tau) of 0.1 seconds. For a voltage step it will take 0.1 seconds until capacitor has charged to 63% of input voltage, and 0.5 seconds until capacitor has charged to 99%. So feeding it even with a 10 Hz square wave signal that has a period of 0.1 seconds would charge the cap to 39% and discharge it to 0%.

Comment: thanks for your effort but unfortunately none of the points that you mentioned explains how the same voltage with the same polarity gets from the one side of the capacitor to its other side in the exact same time. I mean from the simulation that I attached we can see that the exact same voltage signal is on both sides of the capacitor. If this is really true, how exactly it happens? Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: If you have 0 volts over a capacitor so it is discharged, and you set one of the capacitor terminals to 1000 volts, at what voltage is the other capacitor terminal? For simplicity, assume capacitor is not connected to any other circuit at all and no current flows through the capacitor.

Comment: If the capacitor is connected directly to the source of 1000V then that's also the voltage that we'll measure on it (once fully charged). I'd expect in that case prevalence of positive charge one one terminal (connected to the positive terminal of source) and negative charge on the other one.

Comment: But I specifically said only one terminal is connected and no current flows, so there is no way the capacitor would get any charge. Let's try again. Assume you live at 0 feet sea level and have a 3 foot pole so the other end of the pole is at 3 feet above sea level. You move on top of a mountain that is 1000 feet above sea level and place the pole on top of mountain. How long is the 3 foot pole now and at what height are each end of the pole, assuming no one altered the pole length while moving it?

Comment: I'm having a bit difficulties to reflect your example to my question, But to answer your question, pole will remain long 3 feet, it's lower end will be at 100 feet above sea and higher end 1003 feet. Hope it meets your expectations. apart of that, completely agree that there is no reason for  capacitor to be polarized in case that only one of its terminals is connected to the voltage source.

Comment: But in that case second capacitor terminal would be connected to the ground of voltage source through resistor/circuit load (exactly as in attached original image), then my expectation would be that the capacitor terminal connected to the positive source terminal will have a positive voltage against the ground and the other capacitor terminal should have negative voltage against the ground (due to the movement of electrons to and from of the capacitor plates). Does that make sense?

Comment: Now the capacitor question is correct too. So, in your circuit, you have a capacitor, that you can approximate as not being able to charge, so in your circuit, there will mostly be very near 0V over the capacitor, so the output voltage will mostly be very near to input voltage, because, compared to the resistor and the frequency, the capacitor is "very large", and will develop very little voltage over it when being charged in the circuit. If the capacitor were "smaller", or frequency lower, the capacitor would have more time to charge and develop more voltage over it.

Comment: And no, your requirement of one terminal going positive and other terminal going negative makes no sense and would violate laws of physics. If you have a capacitor with 0V, and apply a 1V voltage to your RC circuit, and the cap starts charging, the capacitor voltage increases while resistor voltage decreases. So if capacitor has 0.5V over it, it means there must be 0.5V over the resistor, in order for the whole circuit to sum up to 1V. Basic Kirchoff voltage and current laws apply, Ohm's law, etc.

Comment: This is all very helpful, many thanks for that. I was wondering about it a long time as I came across it in amplifiers where capacitor (C) is used to separate DC from AC and now it makes more sense. As it was several times mentioned here, important is that C is connected inside the closed circle loop (can feel el. field from both sides). However, I'm still wondering how C works when it's used to connect antenna to the circuit because in that case other end of the antenna is not connected to the earth and despite that it still somehow works. Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

One way to think of a capacitor is to see it as a voltage source whose voltage equals to that of the capacitor at any particular moment.

At time zero, the voltage of the capacitor is zero, so the voltage across the resistor equals to the voltage of the AC source.

As current passes across the capacitor, it will charge a bit. Let's say that at time one, it has charged to 0.5 V. In that case the voltage across the resistor becomes:
Vresistor = Vac - Vcap = Vac (t=1) - 0.5 V

If you keep in mind that the capacitor's voltage can't change instantaneously, and track its voltage from moment to moment based on the voltage it had the previous moment plus or minus additional voltage caused by current that went across the capacitor between the current moment and the previous moment, we'll get the graphs like you attached.

There are also such things as phasor equations that track this whole process and can describe the situation at any given moment. But I'd recommend to first understand the process by replacing the capacitor, at any one moment, by a voltage source of the same voltage as that of the capacitor at the same moment. For example pick a point in your graph, check the voltage of the AC source and the capacitor, based on these find the resistor voltage and the current. Then verify that the next moment the voltage across the capacitor changes based on the current you found for the previous moment (increases if current flows from the capacitor's momentary positive voltage side to its momentary less positive \ negative side and vice versa - which side is positive and negative changes with time, not constant, but at a given moment the voltage across the capacitor is constant. These sides are relative to each other, not relative to the AC source, resistor or the rest of the circuit).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm having a difficulties to understand why potential on the resistor at time = 0 should be equal to the AC source. I mean how does it get there through the capacitor which sits in between? I guess you use some sort of simplification in your analysis? For example applying Kirchoff law and you simply split the voltage between capacitor (= 0 because is not charged) and resistor but what is supposed to bring the charge (of the same polarity as source) on the resistor? I'm trying to see the fundamentals of the charge movement in this circuit.

Comment: Yes, by applying Kirchoff law given zero charge on the cap. I know that a capacitor doesn't really let current flow through it. But in EE, we always pretend that it does. In fact at any given moment it's like a voltage source of a particular voltage. I suppose the physics of it is like this: source pushes electrons on the plate of cap closest to it. The first plate pushes the electrons of the seconds plate. The electrons of the second plate flow in the polarity of the source. But really, nobody remembers it like this - they simply either treat cap. as a voltage source at one moment..

Comment: or as impedance element (helps for phasor analysis). falstad.com has a circuit simulator with nice animations. You could see current flowing through the capacitor. It's such a commonly used equivalent in terms of the result, that you can easily forget current doesn't flow through the cap.

Comment: Also the voltage on the cap. is fixed at any given moment (hence you can pretend it's a voltage source). If current flows through the cap, its voltage will - a moment later, not right away - either increase or decrease per the amount of current that went through - regardless of what the rest of the circuit does (cap's voltage only depends on current through in the past that either builds or reduces its voltage).

Comment: it's a simplification, but it's 100% equivalent result, so in terms of accuracy it's not an approximation, but exact. (I feel like the comments are actually better than the answer, so hopefully it helps).

Comment: Another point based on the discussion from the other answer - capacitor never charges \ discharges unless there's a loop for current to flow. If it's attached at the end of a 1000 V wire with no loop (open circuit) - both plates will be at a 1000 V (or a voltage source of zero because it never charged, as no current ever went through it).

Comment: The voltage on the capacitor is proportional to the *net* charge stored in it. When the capacitor initially has zero charge, it must have zero voltage as well. The capacitance is the ratio of charge to voltage, after all.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications. You mentioned that capacitor maintains its potential on both sides. In a circuit with the voltage source it continues doing the same. But my question would be how is that maintenance of potential achieved? Could we say that if first capacitor plate is connected to a positive potential, positive electric field locks/attracts electrons on the second plate and this lack of locked electrons actually results into positive charge also on the second plate?

Comment: And in addition, if we add another capacitor in a series with the first one, the "generated" positive potential on the second plate of the first capacitor will cause the same effect on the second capacitor?

Comment: I can answer the second question: let's say that the second capacitor is added at time t=3. At time t=3, the second capacitor will have zero voltage, as no current had gone through it as of yet. So at time t=3, you could replace it by a zero voltage source (short circuit), and it'd would be the same. At t=3.0001, it would acquire some voltage based on the current that had gone through it. If current went left to right, the left plate, will be higher than the right plate, say by 0.1 V.
Let's say at t=3.0001, Vac = 2, Vcap1 = 0.5, Vcap2 = 0.1. Then Vresistor = 1.4 V.

Comment: Voltage left plate of cap2: Vcap2 (left) = Vac - Vcap1 = 2 - 0.5 = 1.5 V
Voltage right plate of cap2: Vcap2 (right) = Vac - Vcap1 - V(across cap2) = 2 - 0.5 - 0.1 = 1.4 V.

Comment: For the first question: I just wanted to say that usually we pretend that current is made of positive charges and flows from positive to negative (the opposite of reality). I'm just mentioning it, because after some years of thinking that way, people might get confused when a question is framed in what is actually the correct way, like you did (negative charges make up the current), rather than in the "pretend" way. Your questions are great, because not a lot of people stop think about it. But in the same time, thinking of a cap as a V-source and pretending that current flows across it helps.

Comment: On the image you attached of several capacitors, notice that the voltage across them at time = 0 is zero (zero voltage source). The same would be the case if you changed the phase of the AC source to +90deg or 0.5*3.14 radians so it started at its peak rather than at zero. Capacitors are at zero volts before current flows through them.

Comment: Experiment: the phase of the voltage source is zero degrees in the picture. Try changing it to 90degrees. Note that the voltage of the capacitors is zero at time t=0, while the voltage source is at +1V. The resistor will capture the entire 1V at time t=0.

Comment: This is all very helpful, many thanks for that. I was wondering about it a long time as I came across it in amplifiers where capacitor (C) is used to separate DC from AC and now it makes more sense. As it was several times mentioned here, important is that C is connected inside the closed circle loop (can feel el. field from both sides). However, I'm still wondering how C works when it's used to connect antenna to the circuit because in that case other end of the antenna is not connected to the earth and despite that it still somehow works. Any clues?

Comment: I've been thinking about this myself, and the question stands even if there's no C, but simply an antenna and a resistor underneath. I've some ideas, and I posted a question about this here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/629446/monopole-antenna-does-current-flows-in-loops

Comment: @ee_student I guess that in case of antenna, some AC voltage is being inducted on it and that allows it to pass through the C.

Comment: Yes, if the air between the edges of the antenna is like a capacitor. There's some disagreement whether that's the right way to think about..